# Problem with making wheel spokes using array and curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a wheel with the spokes using array and curve modifier, but curve modifier messes things up, what am I doing wrong ?
[image: Result I get after adding the curve modifier]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We would like to help you, but at the moment this question is vague. Could you please specify what the curve modifier is doing? 